# Can a mystic/sage upgrade their own spells?

Tags: everquest-2

I have just started playing EverQuest II as a mystic (solo, FTP, stop judging). I am interested in picking up the sage profession, because they are described as [specializ[ing] in making spell upgrades for mages and healers](http://eq2.zam.com/wiki/Sage_%28EQ2_Profession%29).

However, it is not clear to me if they can do this for themselves, as well as group members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Sages make spells for mages and healers. If you take up that profession then you will be able to upgrade all the spells for your character and others.

A list of recipes and spells a Sage can create can be found here:

http://eq2.wikia.com/wiki/Sage